# How do I know when to use: “completely”, “in full”, “totally” or “entirely”?

Tags: synonyms, adverbs

Does anyone know any rule or pseudo-rule that works to find out when each of the following terms should be used?

Using: *completely* vs *in full* vs *totally* vs *entirely*

I assume they are not completely interchangeable.

Some kind of heuristic rules would allow foreign English speakers to know which one to use in many different sentences.

Just for the sake of an example, find the command sentence below:

> "Unwind the spool of thread completely/in full/totally/entirely."

Thanks

Comment: The OP should show example sentences and usage in context.

Comment: Thanks. I added an example.

Comment: By the way, this question is about English usage. Does anyone why this question is off-topic? Thanks

Comment: I can see it might be closed because you've not looked the words up in a dictionary and compared the definitions, but I don't see why it's judged as off-topic.

Comment: @goahead97, unfortunately it is a very widespread problem on this site that the posted 'reasons' for closing do not reflect what really motivated those who voted to close. Your question is well within the scope of this site, as the terms are really close in meaning and articulating the nuances that distinguish them would be interesting and not at all easy. You should not, however, expect anybody to be able to come up with the rules for their use that learners of English would be able to apply mechanically.

Comment: @jsw29 The problem is that, while native speakers may have intuitions about when *they* personally would use each word, other speakers often disagree; such answers cannot be said to be based on a reliable source. A dictionary is probably your best bet. (Those sorts of "it's how I use it, just trust me" answers tend to irk me because of their unreliability, inability to be shown true or false, and overall questionable value.)

Comment: @alphabet, dictionaries are not one's 'best bet' when it comes to the questions of this sort because they define words separately, one-by-one, and usually do not explicitly compare them. What the OP could find out from dictionaries is that these terms have very similar meanings, which the OP already knows. It is precisely because of the similarities in the dictionary definitions that somebody like the OP may be wondering what the differences are. Engaging such questions (however imperfectly) is one of the ways in which this site can add to what can be found elsewhere.

Comment: @jsw29 I wouldn't call them "imperfect" so much as "so obviously unreliable and opinion-based as to be unsuitable for a question-and-answer site." Corpus research can help settle these, though.

Answer (score 1):

- You'd never hear anyone say 'I'm wasted in full' and rarely 'I'm entirely wasted' though 'I'm completely wasted' and especially 'I'm totally wasted' are more idiomatic. 'Totally' is something of a vogue word, so it pairs well with slang 'wasted'.
- 'Paid in full' is the commonest variant (41.6 million hits on Google, raw data ... see also [these Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=totally+paid%2Centirely+paid%2Ccompletely+paid%2Cpaid+in+full&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)). This is probably because the formal register lends itself to formal situations (commercial transactions). In other situations, this variant is relatively rare.
- 'Was totally typical of' is a far less common variant of 'was completely typical of' and 'was entirely typical of', probably to avoid the excess of *t*'s.
- 'Completely furnished' and 'totally furnished' are far more common than 'entirely furnished', especially when not followed by a prepositional phrase ('by Acme Furnishings', etc). Though 'fully furnished' easily trumps both of them.

But there are many pairings which are far more interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

You can look up **completely, totally, and entirely** yourself. Take note of nuances and context, but there is a lot of overlap.

**In full** is used only in limited contexts:

OED

> **in full.**
>
> **P.2.e.iii.i. With reference to payment, receipt of money owing, etc.: *to the full amount*.**
>
> 1641 Money for pay, you shall have in full, as wee agreed. *Great
> Discoverie Plot Scotl. sig. A4v*
>
> 2012 I wish to purchase whole or part collections of Railwayana...
> Payment is always prompt and in full. *Steam World August 62/2
> (advertisement)*

To this, and more associated with the payment of a debt of honour than of money, we would also have

“He extracted his revenge in full.”

> **P.2.e.iii.ii. With reference to a statement, text, etc.: at full length, in extenso; without abbreviation or abridgement; so as to
> include the full text or particulars.**
>
> 1656 As for his Right, it hath in part been answered at §16. and see
> in full §75. *S. Hunton, Golden Law 8*
>
> 2008 Here, in full, is Turin's review of Lancôme's Tresor. *New Yorker
> 10 March 122/3*

The concept behind “in full” is the reference to a positive **amount** as implied by “full”. Unwinding leaves a negative amount and “full” is inappropriate.

“I cleaned the room in full” does not work either as there is no amount of anything involved.